# How to read only natural numbers from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input to enter a phone number. I need to make it so that the user can enter any characters, for example "fghd6 dhj 3", and only "63" is output to the console. How can I do this?
Now I have regular expressions, but it only passes natural numbers, and I need to be able to enter anything and read only natural numbers.

```js
export default class UserPhone extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      operatorValueState: "",
    };
    this.inputOperatorReference = React.createRef();
    this.operatorValueHandler = this.operatorValueHandler.bind(this);
  }

  operatorValueHandler(e) {
    const regExp = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
    if (e.target.value === "" || regExp.test(e.target.value)) {
      this.setState({ operatorValueState: e.target.value });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.inputOperatorReference.current.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.inputOperatorReference}
          value={this.state.operatorValueState}
          onInput={this.operatorValueHandler}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of what the issue is and [edit] your code snippet so that it is runnable: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537)?

Comment: The unoptimized and dirty way would be to loop through the content and check for IsNaN, if false it is a number, and you could append it to a string

Comment: Please don't be so hostile to your users. Phone numbers can contain other symbols too, like spaces for readability, but e.g. `+` is meaningful. And you will prevent them from copying and pasting from a source that has non-digits in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract numbers from string, if I understand correctly.

Here is how you could do this :

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    const input = event.target.value;

    const numbers = input.match(/\d+/g);

    if (numbers && numbers.length > 0) {
      // logic here
    } else {
      // logic here
    }
  };
```

`input.match(/\d+/g)` will return only numbers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added your code but without "else". Now the input does not allow you to enter different characters and letters, but when you enter two numbers and strip one, then you can enter letters and the first digit is not stripped.

Comment: try to remove `&& numbers.length > 0` ?